# VS2017; how to change solution source control from local git to GitHub?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, version-control, visual-studio-2017

I wasn't paying attention the other night, was really late!  I "committed" a new solution to git, not GitHub. Now every time I try to commit the solution it is asking me for my account info for the "git" provider.  How can I change the solution to use GitHub as the source control, or at the very least reset the settings to default so I can start over (with regards to adding to source control).

Comment: Kind of, changing the global settings let me to be able to then find and publish to GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to connnect local repo with github in VS:

#### Option 1: change the remote URL as github repo URL

Local repu in VS -> Team Explorer -> Settings -> Repository Settings -> Edit remote origin URL -> change the URL as a github repo URL -> Save.

[image]

Now when you push the changes, it will push to the github repo.

#### Option 2: install github extension in VS

You can install [**GitHub Extension for Visual Studio**](https://visualstudio.github.com/), then you can clone a github repo and commit and push to github.

#### Note:

Even you connect other remote repo for now, it shouldn’t asking any info unless the global username and email address are not set. So please also check the global settings:

Team Explorer -> Settings -> Global Settings -> make sure the username and email address are specified.

[image]

Comment: I marked it correct as it probably did work.  The first thing I did was change the global settings to match my GitHub. After that all the GitHub options returned. I still don't know how this worked and have spent some time trying to figure it out, hence the delay.  Now is Adobe Premiere pro would have a GitHub setup for video projects!